# Simple 2D motion vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, differentiation

I am curious if the initial velocity of  $x(t)=-3-4t+2t^2$  can be calculated from only this given in another way than just differentiation, by using the constant acceleration formulas perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am somewhat puzzled by the title to your question.

Compare your equation with the constant acceleration kinematic equation $x(t) =x_0+v_0t+\frac 12 a t^2$